# File exceeds the maximum file size, google apps + google drive

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I'm trying to use Google Scripts for uploading user's files to my Google Drive.

I deployed my google scipt as web app. I have two files:

**form.html**

```
<div id="output"></div>
    <form id="myForm">
        <input type="hidden" name="user_id" id="user_id" value="<?= user_id ?>">
        <input type="file" name="myFile">
        <input type="submit" id="upload_button" value="Upload File"
            onclick="this.value='Uploading..';
                google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(fileUploaded)
                .uploadFiles(this.parentNode);
                return false;">
    </form>

<script>
function fileUploaded(status) {
    document.getElementById('upload_button').value = "Upload File";
    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = status;
}
</script>

<style>
input { display:block; margin: 20px; }
</style>
```

**server.gs**

```
function folderExists(name) {
    var folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(name);
    return folders.hasNext();
}

function createForm(uid) {
    var t = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('form.html');
    t.user_id = uid;
    return t.evaluate().setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.NATIVE);
}

function doGet(e) {
    var uid = e.parameters.user_id;

    if (uid && folderExists(uid))
        return createForm(uid);

    return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('<b>Request is not valid</b>');
}

function uploadFiles(form) {

    try {

        var uid = form.user_id;
        var folder, folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(uid);

        if (folders.hasNext()) {
            folder = folders.next();
        } else {
            return "Unable to upload file";
        }

        var blob = form.myFile;
        var file = folder.createFile(blob);

        return "File uploaded successfully";

        } catch (error) {
            return error.toString();
    }  
}
```

I'm trying to upload a 48 Mb file and receive an Exception:

> Exception: File  exceeds the maximum file size.

Do Google has some limitations for pushing files to Drive? I'm using 1 TB plan.

**EDIT:**

I'm trying to use

```
Drive.Files.insert
```

function. It has the limit: Maximum file size: 5120GB as described here: https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/insert

So, in that case I also can not upload a file to my Google Drive and receive this:

> Exception: Empty response

Comment: I think you have similar problems with the users in the [issues tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=552#c27).  It looks like the limit is 10MB and it is suggested that you use Google Drive service for uploading the file. Instead of what you are using above.

Comment: @gerardnimo the referred issue correspond to DocList service which was deprecated. Anyway, there is an issue regarding DriveApp service: [3977](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=3977)